# Is react-helmet-async enough for SEO?

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I am a fan of single page applications (spa) especially when it comes to react spa.
So I was wondering if using react-helmet-async is sufficient enough to give the spa the basics of SEO or is it needed to migrate to nextjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think that if you want good SEO, you should choose server-side rendering rather than using this component. It only lets you modify the content of certain tags. Search engines need more than header metadata.

React helmet is very useful for optimizing social media previews. It can provide metadata with the information that social networks display when someone shares a link to your site.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what you want... key questions:

- How is your content received and show
- Do you want (need) SSR?
- Is your content static?

If the second one is a yes, you should consider Next.js (or another framework or library) that provides you with such capability
Remember, react-helmet-async will provide you with capabilities on the client side, so, no SSR is involved.

I hope to give you some help